# ¿Editar celda de tabla en clase distinta a la que pertenece la tabla? Java

Tags: java

alguien me podría ayudar con el siguiente problema.

Tengo dos clases, en una de ella tengo una tabla la cual contiene una fila y sus respectivos datos. Mi problema es a la hora de querer editar los datos de dicha tabla en una clase distinta a la que fue creada me saca El sigiente error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

A la hora de hacer un tabla.getRowCount() en la clase donde está la tabla me pone el respectivo 1 de la fila, pero si uso la misma función en una clase distinta, ésta siempre me saca 0.

Alguien me podría ayudar por favor, éste sería el código de manera resumida:

Clase que contiene la tabla:

```
public class Tests {
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;

    void test(){
        try {
            String cabecera[] = {"Id","Name"};
            String datos[][] = {};
            model = new DefaultTableModel(datos, cabecera);
            table = new JTable(model);

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            JButton b=new JButton("Btn"); 
            JButton b2=new JButton("Other window");    
            b.setBounds(100,100,140, 40);        
            b2.setBounds(50,100,60, 40);    
            f.add(b); 
            f.add(b2); 
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            f.setVisible(true);

            b.addActionListener((ActionEvent arg0) -> {
                String data[]={"Dato1","dato2"};
                model.addRow(data);          
            });
            b2.addActionListener((ActionEvent arg0) -> {
                Instant i = new Instant();          
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Tests t = new Tests();
        t.test();
    }
}
```

Clase secundaria que quiero usar para modificar celdas de la tabla:

```
public class Instant {

    public Instant(){
        try {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            JButton b=new JButton("Other");    
            b.setBounds(100,100,140, 40);    
            f.add(b); 
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            f.setVisible(true);

            b.addActionListener((ActionEvent arg0) -> {
                Tests t = new Tests();
                DefaultTableModel model = t.model;
                model.setValueAt("123123123", 0, 0);          
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = new Instant();
    }
}
```

La clase 2 es donde me gustaría modificar los datos de las celdas de la tabla, pero al usar el código que hay en el main de la clase 2, éste me aparece el error de que no hay ninguna fila. Alguien me ayudaría con éste problema, por favor?

Comment: Podrías aportar algo más del código?

Comment: Si no pones el código donde estás manipulando la tabla y cómo obtienes su referencia en esa clase es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Ya añadí el código de manera resumida. Alguno tiene idea de cómo podría realizar ésto, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Así como lo tienes configurado tu clase Instant usa el modelo (DefaultTableModel) de la tabla de tu clase Tests. Por lo que el main de Instant no va funcionar ya que Tests no está inicializada y su modelo está vacío.

La clase Instant se invoca cuando pulsas el botón b2 de la clase Tests. De ahí se muestra la Frame de Instant. Y además te va seguir tronando si no has alimentado información a la tabla antes. O sea, si no has pulsado el botón b, antes.

Quita el main de Instant, o cámbialo a que sea exactamente igual al main de Tests.